# How to get Position of turtlebot?

Tags: localization, navigation, odometry, rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my question is: how do i get the position of my turtlebot in the room?
I followed the instuctions from the website [lear.turtlebot](http://learn.turtlebot.com). I modified the code for my own issues but now my question is: when i am sending a new goal to my turtlebot (initialized as a SimpleActionClient from actionlib), using a MoveBaseGoal: where do i get the precise position of my turtlebot during the driving from?

I tried for example:

```
rospy.Subscriber("odom", Odometry, self.Position)

def Position(self, msg):
    print msg.pose.pose
```

the problem here is, that the values of position.x and position.y are not the right ones, because the turtlebot ends up in the right place where i wanted it to be, but the printed information is totally wrong.

The right information is existent in rviz: a client that I use to set the initial position of my turtlebot.

Another way that i found is using a TransformListener but every tutorial i found did not work in my place. In my opinion the prblem here is that i have no idea how the topics or frames are called.

Does anyone can help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222504/how-to-get-position-of-turtlebot?/) by [volleybug](https://answers.ros.org/users/25328/volleybug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that the `odom` topic contains the pose of the turtlebot in the `/odom` frame. This pose will drift relative to the ground truth pose as the turtlebot drives around. This is due to a variety of factors such as error in the kinematic model and wheel slippage. Due to this drift, if you are trying to control your turtlebot to a fixed location in a static environment (such as a room), the `odom` topic is not enough.

Are you using a map? If so, you are also likely using [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) to "localize" your robot. In this case, you should be either transforming the pose information in the `odom` topic into the `/map`  frame, or you should be looking up the transform from the `/map` frame to the `/base` frame.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0